# ¿Cómo apuntar a una app en Heroku con un dominio en Hostinger?

Tags: heroku, dns, endpoint

He comprado un dominio en hostinger **[educoursesv.com](http://educoursesv.com/)** y tengo accesso a la DNS Zone, es a lo único que me permite entrar el hpanel, tengo una app hecha y desplegada en heroku de forma gratuita, ya logré apuntar a la app en heroku con el subdominio **[www.educoursesv.com](http://www.educoursesv.com/)** pero no puedo entrar sin el **www** ya configure los CNAME apuntando a la app y sigo sin poder verlo, muestro mi configuración DNS en Hostinger y en Heroku tengo adicionados los dominios con www y sin www, no cuento con servidor físico, todo es en la nube. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

```
CNAME (Alias)

Host            Points to                           TTL
@               educourseelsalvador.herokuapp.com   14400
autoconfig      autoconfig.hostinger.com            14400
cpanel          clcp.hostinger.com                  14400
phpmyadmin      clcp.hostinger.com                  14400
webmail         clcp.hostinger.com                  14400
www             educourseelsalvador.herokuapp.com   1800
```

Comment: lograste algo al respecto? justo ahora quiero implementar lo mismo que tu, tengo un dominio en hostinger y quiero apuntar al server gratuito de heroku. Me ayudarías mucho Gracias